# How can we integrate Android management API in asp.net core APIs?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, android-management-api

I want to integrate Android management API in asp.net core APIs.
I want to add below functionalities:

1. signupUrls
2. Create Enterprises
3. register devices and policies

I did lots of r&d and read google documents but I didn't find any solution to integrate above functionalities in asp.net core API.

Google provides so many documents, but I don't understand them properly.

Google provides **Android Management API Client Library for .NET** but i don't understand that how can i use in my project. They provide NuGet package **Google.Apis.AndroidManagement.v1** but how can i use it in my project.

They provide API endpoints, but no any code example that how can we integrate.

I am referring below documents -

1. https://developers.google.com/android/management/create-enterprise
2. https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/androidmanagement/v1

**Document-1 provide Java code but how can we use the same kind of code in asp.net framework.**

If anybody have idea about this then please help me. ***I am stuck, helpless and hopeless.***

*Thanks in advance!!*

Answer (score 0):

To integrate Android Management API to your project, you first need to import the client library. In your case, [.NET library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/androidmanagement/v1). Then follow the next steps [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/get_started#finding-information-about-the-apis). You should be able to call the API once done.

Unfortunately, the Android Management API documentation does not provide sample code written in .NET.